# How to connect Grafana running in a Docker container to a Prometheus data source running on the host machine (on Docker for Mac)?

Tags: docker, go, prometheus, grafana, docker-network

I've started a Prometheus server at `localhost:57475/metrics`:

[image]

using the following Go code:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "contrib.go.opencensus.io/exporter/prometheus"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "go.opencensus.io/plugin/ochttp"
    "go.opencensus.io/stats/view"
)

func main() {
    stop := make(chan struct{})

    server := &http.Server{Addr: ":8080"}

    statsMux := http.NewServeMux()
    statsServer := &http.Server{Handler: statsMux, Addr: ":57475"}

    if err := view.Register(ochttp.DefaultServerViews...); err != nil {
        log.WithError(err).Fatal("register HTTP metrics view")
    }

    exporter, err := prometheus.NewExporter(prometheus.Options{
        Namespace: "default",
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.WithError(err).Fatal("create Prometheus exporter")
    }

    view.RegisterExporter(exporter)

    statsMux.Handle("/metrics", exporter)

    originalHandler := http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("Hello, World!"))
    })
    och := &ochttp.Handler{
        Handler: originalHandler,
    }

    server.Handler = och

    go func() {
        log.Info("Starting stats server...")
        if err := statsServer.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
            log.WithError(err).Fatal("listen and serve stats")
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        log.Info("Starting server...")
        if err := server.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
            log.WithError(err).Fatal("listen and serve service endpoints")
        }
    }()

    <-stop
}
```

I've also started Grafana in a container using the following command (following https://grafana.com/docs/installation/docker/):

```
> docker run --detach --publish 3000:3000  --env "GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=secret" grafana/grafana
2a17ad2bcc05e2955190129b981b3329cd2c5e89098e28b443337ac79ed607f2
```

In Grafana, I would like to connect to the Prometheus exporter running on my Mac `localhost`. Following https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/, I've tried to use the special DNS name `host.docker.internal`, so specifying the URL as `http://host.docker.internal:57475/metrics`. However, this results in an `HTTP Error Not Found` when I click "Save & Test":

[image]

Any idea why this is not working?

### Update

Instead of using the special DNS name `host.docker.internal`, I tried combining the server and Grafana into a Docker Compose multi-container application and using the Docker bridge to connect them, but this also didn't work. With the follwoing directory structure:

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
└── server
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── go.mod
    ├── go.sum
    └── main.go
```

and the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    build: ./server
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "57475:57475"
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

and the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM golang:1.12

WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY . .

RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN go install -v ./...

CMD ["app"]
```

If I attach to the Grafana container and curl `server:8080` or `server:57475/metrics`, I get a response:

```
useprometheus> docker exec -it --user root useprometheus_grafana_1 /bin/ash
/usr/share/grafana # apk add curl
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/3) Installing nghttp2-libs (1.39.2-r0)
(2/3) Installing libcurl (7.66.0-r0)
(3/3) Installing curl (7.66.0-r0)
Executing busybox-1.30.1-r2.trigger
OK: 17 MiB in 24 packages
/usr/share/grafana # curl server:8080
Hello, World!/usr/share/grafana # curl server:57475/metrics
# HELP default_opencensus_io_http_server_latency Latency distribution of HTTP requests
# TYPE default_opencensus_io_http_server_latency histogram
default_opencensus_io_http_server_latency_bucket{le="1"} 1
default_opencensus_io_http_server_latency_bucket{le="2"} 1
default_opencensus_io_http_server_latency_bucket{le="3"} 1
default_opencensus_io_http_server_latency_bucket{le="4"} 1
```

However, if I try to add the same URL in the Grafana admin, I get the same error:

[image]

In other words, although I am able to `curl` this endpoint from the Grafana container, I can't use it as a data source URL in the Grafana dashboard, making me think this is something Grafana-specific. Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: use your host ip to connect or use --network host in your docker run container and use localhost to conect

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out I didn't quite understand how Prometheus works. The Go application in the example creates a Prometheus *exporter*, which still has to be scraped by a Prometheus *server*, which in turn is the data source for Grafana.

I modified the directory structure to be like this:

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── prometheus
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── prometheus.yml
└── server
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── go.mod
    ├── go.sum
    └── main.go
```

where `docker-compose.yml` is

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    build: ./server
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "57475:57475"
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
  prometheus:
    build: ./prometheus
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
```

and the `prometheus/Dockerfile` is

```
FROM prom/prometheus

ADD prometheus.yml /etc/prometheus
```

and the `prometheus/prometheus.yml` is

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'server'

    static_configs:
      - targets: ['server:57475']
```

Now I'm able to add `prometheus:9090` as a data source URL:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

GRAFANA - PROMETHEUS
This will work as long as you have both your Grafana and Prometheus running as a docker images so before you begin please  run the command below to be sure that both prometheus and Grafana images are up by running this command  'docker ps'

If they are not up, please run this command on the terminal

```
docker run -p 9090:9090 prom/prometheus .
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 grafana/grafana-enterprise
```

To connect the prometheus to GRAFANA, you will need to get the prometheus server IP address that is running as a docker image from host. Use this command on your terminal to display all the container IDs docker ps -a

You will see your prometheus server container ID displayed for example "faca0c893603". Please copy the ID and run the command below on your terminal to see the IP address of your Prometheus server

`docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' faca0c893603`

Note : (faca0c893603 is the ContainerID of the prom/prometheus server) When you run the command it will display the IP address(172.17.0.4) of the Prometheus container which needs to be mapped with the port of the prometheus server on Grafana.

On data source on Grafana, put this on the URL http://172.17.0.3:9090 and try to save and test

Answer (score 0):

Add `--network host` to your `docker run` command:

`docker run --network host...`

Then use `localhost:[prometheus_port]` in Grafana settings

Relevant [docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/)

Comment: If I try this and try to `curl http://localhost:3000/`, I get `Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused` (that is, I'm not able to see the Grafana dashboard at all)

Comment: did Grafana container start? it's probably down.

Comment: The service is running, I can see `grafana_1  | t=2019-11-04T20:48:07+0000 lvl=info msg="HTTP Server Listen" logger=http.server address=0.0.0.0:3000 protocol=http subUrl= socket=` in the logs from `docker-compose up` (in the second example where I specify `network: "host"` in the `docker-compose.yml`).